# convert 3 arrays into 1 array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I have one array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => et6CX
)
Array
(
    [0] => fxYlw
)
Array
(
    [0] => APA91
)
```

I want result like

```
Array
(

    [0] => et6CX
    [1] => fxYlw
    [2] => APA91
)
```

How it can be done? I have tried array_values(), array_merge(), etc functions but nothings goes right.

I am building an app in Laravel5.2 and this issue comes in fetching record I think. Please have a look as soon as possible

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are they 3 arrays ?

Comment: it's actually 1 array only but 3 times pushed into one array so it gives 3 different arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
<?php

$x = [['a'],['b'],['c']];

$y = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item[0];
},$x);

var_dump($y);
```

Output:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "b" [2]=> string(1) "c" }
```

Comment: Tips: `array_map('current', $x)`. Done :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried with merge, and it seems to works perfectly.
DO you have mode details about how you use it in your code ?

```
<?php
// Data
$a = ['a'];
$b = ['b'];
$c = ['c'];

// Method 1
var_dump( $e = array_merge($a) );
var_dump( $e = array_merge($e, $b) );
var_dump( $e = array_merge($e, $c) );

// Method 2
var_dump( array_merge($a, $b, $c) );
```

And I get correct values:

Method1:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'a' (length=1)

array (size=2)
  0 => string 'a' (length=1)
  1 => string 'b' (length=1)

array (size=3)
  0 => string 'a' (length=1)
  1 => string 'b' (length=1)
  2 => string 'c' (length=1)
```

Method 2:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'a' (length=1)
  1 => string 'b' (length=1)
  2 => string 'c' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $array = //Your array
    $new_array = array();
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array);$i++)
    {
        array_push($new_array,$array[$i][0]);
    }

    print_r($new_array);
```